# How to interpret the pixel array derived from CMSampleBuffer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, avfoundation

Maybe this is a very stupid question.
I am using AVFoundation in my app and I am able to get the frames(32BGRA Format). 
The width of the frame is 1504, Height is 1128 and the bytes-Per-Row value is 6016. 
When I create a UInt8 pixel array from this samplebuffer the length (array.count) of this array is 1696512 which happens to be equal to width * height.

What I am not getting is why the array length is width * height. Should it not be width * height * 4.

What am I missing here?

Edit - 1: Code

```
func BufferToArray(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> ([UInt8], Int, Int, Int) {

    var rgbBufferArray = [UInt8]()

    //Get pixel Buffer from CMSSampleBUffer
    let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

    //Lock the base Address
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
    //get pixel count
    let pixelCount = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer) * CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

    //Get base address
    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)

    //Get bytes per row of the image
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)

    //Cast the base address to UInt8. This is like an array now
    let frameBuffer = baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)


    rgbBufferArray = Array(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: frameBuffer, count: pixelCount))


    //Unlock and release memory
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

return (rgbBufferArray, bytesPerRow, width, height)
```

}

Comment: How are you creating the array? Could you maybe post some code please?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Code added. Can you please look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the data type (`UInt8`) in combination with the `count`:

You are assuming the memory contains `UInt8` values (`assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)`) of `pixelCount` count. But as you concluded correctly it should be four times that number.

I'd recommend you `import simd` and use `simd_uchar4` as data type. That's a struct type containing 4 `UInt8`. Then your array will contain `pixelCount` values of 4-tuple pixel values. You can access the channels with `array[index].x` , `.y`, `.z`, and `.w` respectively.